# Nested dictionary nullreferenceexception using linq and entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to populate a dictionary using a nested select, and I get nullreference exception, since objects from TableC might not exists.

```
List<SomeResult> test = (from a in _entities.TableA
                         select new SomeResult
                         {
                            TestB = a.TableB.Name,
                            TestCDict = a.TableC.ToDictionary(x => x.SomeKey, x => x.SomeValue)
                          }).ToList();
```

How do I fix so TestCDict can be null?

/Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
TestCDict = a.TableC == null ? null
            : a.TableC.ToDictionary(x => x.SomeKey, x => x.SomeValue)
```

Or to this, if you want an empty dictionary instead of null in `TestCDict`:

```
TestCDict = a.TableC == null ? new Dictionary<TypeOfKey, TypeOfValue>()
            : a.TableC.ToDictionary(x => x.SomeKey, x => x.SomeValue)
```

Comment: Seems to be more of a reference problem. I might need to use some nested query to "include" the values from TableC. Says that it only can compare basic things as string, int and not of type entity